# How can i delete that Padding in report between records

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

How can i delete that padding in report between records in below image
how can solve that

[image]

Comment: I have no idea who upvoted this question... Please add code and embed that picture. How should anybody answer this question without knowing the XML code behind that picture?

Answer (score 0):

Please specifiy `<style>` inside your report to change your styling.

If your records are in `<tr>` then add this.

```
<style type="text/css">
    tr{
      padding:0px;
      margin:0px;
      }
</style>
```